# Knockout-validation not displaying error message for select multiple

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I set up a page with the knockout validation plugin for validating user input. I have two elements: one is a regular `select` and the other is `select` with `multiple` set. The idea is to make both elements are required.

The validation call is firing, but the problem is that the error message for the select multiple is not displaying.

Here is my js code:

```
  ko.validation.init();

    function isNotUndefined(val) {
        return (typeof val != "undefined");
    }

    function isArrayNotEmpty(val) {
        return (val.length > 0);
    }

    var viewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.memberType = ko.observable().extend({
            validation: {validator: isNotUndefined, message:'Please select gender'}
        });
        self.seekingTypes = ko.observableArray().extend({
            validation: {validator: isArrayNotEmpty, message:'At least one option is required'}
        });
        self.memberTypeSource = [
            { id: 1, text: 'Man' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Woman' }
        ];
        self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
        self.doValidation = function () {
            console.log('error count=' + self.errors().length);
            if (self.errors().length == 0) {
                console.log('Yay.');
            } else {
                self.errors.showAllMessages(true);
            }
        };

        return {
            memberType: self.memberType,
            seekingTypes: self.seekingTypes,
            memberTypeSource: self.memberTypeSource,
            errors: self.errors,
            doValidation: self.doValidation,

        }
    };

    addEventListener('load', function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

And this is the html:

```html
Gender: <select data-bind="value: memberType,
                    options: memberTypeSource,
                    optionsText: 'text',
                    optionsValue: 'id',
                    optionsCaption: 'Please select'"></select>
<br />
Seeking: <select data-bind="selectedOptions: seekingTypes,
                    options: memberTypeSource,
                    optionsText: 'text',
                    optionsValue: 'id'"
                 multiple></select>
<br />

<button type="button" data-bind='click: doValidation'>Submit</button>
```

I've also tested the validation with input text element, the error message is displayed fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The validation plugin only amends the `value` and `checked` binding to make them automatically "validation" compatible.

So the `selectedOptions` is not automatically validated so you need to call `makeBindingHandlerValidatable` with the `selectedOptions` before the `ko.applyBindings` to make the validation work with your multi select:

```
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable('selectedOptions');
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5wrjzm/).

As an alternative solution you can also you the `validationCore` (or the [`validationMessage` binding](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) on separate span) on your select:

```
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: seekingTypes,
                    options: memberTypeSource,
                    optionsText: 'text',
                    optionsValue: 'id', validationCore: seekingTypes" 
                    multiple></select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzs7y9wo/).

Comment: thanks a lot for providing not one but three solutions for my problem, really appreciate it. BTW Do you happen to know where can i find good documentation on knockout-validation (apart from the one on wiki page at github)?

Comment: Which version of KO is `makeBindingHandlerValidatable` available in? I get an error saying `makeBindingHandlerValidatable is not a functon`...

Comment: @Azimuth this function is part of the KO validation library, however I don't know in which version it was added. It is working fine in the 2.0.3 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min.js and also with the version 1.0.2 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/1.0.2/knockout.validation.min.js

Comment: @Azimuth I got the same error, this one worked for me: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js